# axiosのonUploadProgressですぐに100%が返ってきてしまう。

Tags: javascript

お世話になります。

axiosを利用してファイルのアップロードを行っているのですが、
アップロード要求を出した直後にonUploadProgressイベントが発生し、
loadedの値がtotalと同じく6029440(byte)で返ってきてしまいます。
(このtotalサイズは正しいです)

しかし、ネットワークキャプチャを取得してみると
まだファイルのデータを転送しており、
onUploadProgressイベントが発生してから4分程度後に転送が完了します。
(onUploadProgressイベントは1回しか発生しません)

上記の現象が発生する原因について何かご存知でしたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

現象が発生している環境は以下の通りです。もし情報足りない場合はご指摘頂けたらと思います。
axios : 0.21.1
os    : windows 10
ブラウザ : Edge 92.0.902.84 (他のブラウザ(Firefox, Chrome)でも同じ現象になります)

以下のようなソースで実行しており、onUpload関数内で出力したコンソール出力が
”debug progress 6029440 6029440”となります。

```
const URL = `/upload/uploadtest.bin`;
const config = {
  url: URL,
  method: 'post',
  onUploadProgress: onUpload,
  headers: head,
  data: contentBuffer,
};
const downloadClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: Const.BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  timeout: 0,
});
const res = await downloadClient.request(config);

onUpload(e) {
  console.debug('debug progress', e.loaded, e.total);
  let progress = Math.floor((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
  this.progressUp = progress;
},
```

大変恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願い致します。